# SharePoint 2010 Survey Add Title Header on Survey Page

Tags: 2010, survey

I am new to the Sharepoint and was working with the Sharepoint Surveys. 
I had created a survey and needed to add the survey title to the Survey Dialog Page.
I was able to edit the NewForm.aspx under the created survey in the SharePoint Designer and this worked.

But this requirement is not just for one survey. I need a title header for any surveys added.
And the user cannot edit the NewForm.aspx for each survey in Sharepoint designer everytime. 
Is there any way i can customize the Survey Form or some Master Page to always show the survey title.
Can Somone kindly guide me on this.....